# Ускорение разработки где хранить куски кода? html,css,js,php

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, visual-studio-code, сниппет

работаю с html,css,js,php в vscode понял что много времени трачу на верстку, хотелось бы узнать какой инструмент для хранения и использование наработок использовать эффективнее всего. Сейчас пользуюсь gists но там уже много гистов по php, а верстка это по сути другая категория боюсь чтобы оно не путалось друг с другом возможно ли создавать категории подкатегории для гистов!? или вообще где посоветуете хранить наработки? может плагины какие к vscode есть для структурирования сниппетов в боковой панели или что то подобное? что посоветуете? рад буду любой помощи, ссылкам на статьи, рассказам как вы ускоряете разработку и тд тп. Спасибо.

**Для тех кому лень читать отдельно главное:**

Где вы храните наработки по верстке и вообще код для повторного использования?

Как ускорить верстку? (препроцессоры и еммет не предлагать уже пользуюсь)

Comment: создайте одну репу а в ней сайт

Comment: Проще всего делать это в едином репозитории проекта. Подели на отдельные ветки, если сомневаешься, что может всё смешаться, а далее уже сливай по мере готовности

Answer (score 1):

Ранее, когда работал в windows, использовал "иерархический текстовый редактор [notik](http://www.vitalik.info/notik/)"

Было очень удобно создавать разделы с кучей подразделов, и всё сохранять там (все модули, функции, апишки и пр). Но теперь для мака буду искать альтернативы.

Немного подумав, просто создал каталог в дропбоксе, открыл его в том же vscode, в котором и работаю, и каталогизирую по поддиректориям вместе с файлами (кусками кода). Получилось удобное иерархиризированное меню слево. Всё в одной программе, да и сразу же в облако попадает, чтобы не пропало.